# Elasticsearch query taking a lot of time to retrieve documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Query is taking 116 ms - 30 ms. It retrieves 500 records. Anyway to improve it?

```
POST 'http://localhost:9200/txt/_search?routing=123' -data-raw { _source": {
"includes": [
  "userId",
  "date",
  "tra_id",
  "amount",
  "channel",
  "a_id",
  "category",
  "name",
  "me_name",
  "pending"
]}, "size": 10000, "query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "term": {
        "userId": "123"
      }
    },
    {
      "range": {
        "date": {
          "gte": "2020-01-01",
          "lte": "2020-03-31"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}}}
```

I tried indexing userId with schema as Keyword instead of text. Also added date to the schema. Is the date filtering causing delays?

Answer (score 0):

**One big reason of performance issue is having `size` param value as `10000`,** if you don't give `size` param explicitly its default value is `10` and Elasticsearch has chosen this value carefully.

Please read official doc on [size param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size), In short

**Size param tells Elasticsearch to return that many docs, you may be having 100k matching docs but by default elasticsearch returns only 10 docs, this way it saves the cost of building and fetching all docs and send them on network. if you want next docs you can use the from/size param as mentioned in link I provided.**